# Selecting static values to union into another query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Essentially, my problem is that I need to run a query in Oracle that unions a static list of values ('Static' meaning it's obtained from somewhere else that I cannot get from the database, but is actually an arbitrary list of values I plug into the query) with a dynamic list of values returned from a query.

So, my initial query looks like:

```
select * from (select ('18776') as instanceid from dual) union (<more complex query>)
```

I think, hooray!  And then try to do it with a longer list of static values.  Turns out, I get 'Missing Right Parenthesis' if I try to run:

```
select ('18776','18775') as instanceid from dual
```

So, my basic issue is how can I integrate a list of static values into this union?

NOTE: This is a simplified example of the problem.  The actual list is generated from an API before I generate a query, and so this list of "static" values is unpredictably and arbitrarily large.  I'm not dealing with just 2 static values, it is an arbitrary list.

Comment: Create a STATIC_INSTANCE_ID table, and put them there. `select * from (select instanceid from STATIC_INSTANCE_ID ) union (<more complex query>)` If this is really to be considered static, this should work.

Comment: @ppeterka66 For purposes of this question, they are static in the sense that they are passed into the query as I'm assembling it.  They are generated from another API that is called before I construct the query.  I don't have the ability to create a table to put them in, either.

Comment: what do you do with the results of this query? I mean do you use the values returned in an application, or is it going to be used within the premises of SQL - I mean joining it in a query, using it in a stored procedure, etc?

Comment: @ppeterka66 The results are used in an inner join to further refine a larger main set of data.  Essentially, this is part of a list of filters being applied to a search UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select '18776' as instanceid from dual union all
select '18775' as instanceid from dual
```

or

```
select column_value from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('18776', '18775'))
```

or some sort of hierarchical query that could take your comma separated-string and split it into a set of varchars.

Union these to your initial query.

**update**: "I'm not dealing with just 2 static values, it is an arbitrary list."

Still can pass to a query as a collection (below is just one of many possible approaches)

```
23:15:36 LKU@sandbox> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\sandbox\BUFFER_LKU_39.sql

  1  declare
  2    cnt int := 10;
  3    coll sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  4  begin
  5    coll.extend(cnt);
  6    for i in 1 .. cnt loop
  7      coll(i) := dbms_random.string('l', i);
  8    end loop;
  9    open :result for 'select * from table(:c)' using coll;
 10* end;
23:37:03  11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.50
23:37:04 LKU@sandbox> print result

COLUMN_VALUE
-------------------------------------------------------------
g
kd
qdv
soth
rvwnq
uyfhbq
xxvxvtw
eprralmd
edbcajvfq
ewveyljsjn

10 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to break it into two subqueries:

```
select *
from ((select '18776' as instanceid from dual) 
      union
      (select '18775' as instanceid from dual) 
      union
      (<more complex query>)
     ) t;
```

Note that `union all` performs better than `union`.  If you know there are no duplicates (or duplicates don't matter) then use `union all` instead.

Comment: Suppose that list was 50 - 100 values long.  I could generate that SQL statement in code to do so, but it seems like there might be a better way?  It seems awful wordy to expand that beyond a few.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability/permission to create a table type, you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE TYP_NUMBER_TABLE AS TABLE OF NUMBER(11);
```

And then you can use the TABLE function to select from a instance of that type that you initialize on the fly in your SQL:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(TYP_NUMBER_TABLE(1, 2, 3));
```

Result:

```
COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
           3
```